# Avoiding order dependency in typed python

Tags: python-3.x, types

I am playing with typed python. It's mostly working well but I am having
to reorder a lot of my code because of order dependencies. For example
consider this toy code:

```
from typing import ClassVar, List

class MyFirstClass:
    attr: MyClass

class MyClass:
    # You can optionally declare instance variables in the class body
    attr: int

class MySecondClass:
    attr: MyClass
```

This fails to compile properly because `MyClass` is not declared
in MyFirstClass:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Temp.py", line 5, in <module>
    class MyFirstClass:
  File "Temp.py", line 6, in MyFirstClass
    attr: MyClass
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Irritating. Is there anyway around this? Am I doing something wrong?
The best I have come up with so far as defining MyClass twice, first
time with no body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way around it is a future-import:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

This causes Python to not evaluate the annotations at runtime and instead just attaches them to `__annotations__` as strings.

This change is described in [PEP 563 - Postponed evaluation of annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). Do note that it requires Python 3.7+.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!